# Get Bing Background VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Basically, what I'm trying to do is grab the background image from the `bgDiv` element on Bing and use it as the form background. This is what I have so far.

```
Try
    With bingCheck
        Dim bgDiv As HtmlElement = .Document.GetElementById("bgDiv")
        Dim imgUrl As String = bgDiv.Style("background-image").ToString

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(imgUrl), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse, Net.HttpWebResponse)
        Dim grabbedImage As Image = Image.FromStream(response.GetResponseStream)
        response.Close()

        Me.BackgroundImage = grabbedImage
        Me.Update()
    End With
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

This doesn't seem to work so are there any other ideas on how I can do it?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Did you debug? What is the value of response and grabbedImage?

Comment: I recieved this error:
`Conversion from string "background-image" to type 'Integer' is not valid.`

Answer (score 1):

First things first: the error you get is because you try to call an indexer (with a string key) on a string, and it only has an integer indexer. You could know this by looking at the [`System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement.Style property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.style.aspx):

> Gets or sets a comma-delimited list of styles for the current element.

It will return all the styles currently on the element, but as a long string. There are two other methods of getting the value in a different manner, see below.

After looking at the Style property contents, it contains the following:

> "left: 0px; top: -0.5px; width: 1000px; height: 563px; opacity: 1; background-image: url("http://be.bing.com/az/hprichbg?p=rb%2fPenzanceHarbor_ROW9689010992_1366x768.jpg");"

You can easily retrieve the value with this method:

```
Dim bgimage As String
bgimage = Array.Find(Of String)(bgDiv.Style.Split("; "),
                                Function(s As String) s.Contains("background-image")) _ 
          .Replace("background-image:", "") _
          .Trim()
```

But yet there is one problem, see the last paragraph.

About those two other methods.

The first method is by invoking the [`HtmlDocument.InvokeScript(String, Object()) Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1a88bz.aspx). This will execute a given JavaScript function with the provided parameters and return the (return)value of that function. Now, which function can we use? Well, we can use `eval` for this, with the expression to return the background image of the `bgDiv` element. The code will look like this:

```
Dim bgimage As String
bgImage = bingCheck _
          .Document _
          .InvokeScript("eval",
                        {"window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(""bgDiv"")).backgroundImage"})
```

Which returns the following value:

> url("http://be.bing.com/az/hprichbg?p=rb%2fPenzanceHarbor_ROW9689010992_1366x768.jpg")

Now I think it is quite simple to extract the URL from there on.

Now the second method would be to accessing the COM object itself. This requires you to reference the `Microsoft HTML Object Library` (it is a COM reference!!). Afterwards, you can use the `mshtml` namespace.

After retrieving the bgDiv element in code, we cast the DomElement to a COM object and we can access the properties through there. Following code does that:

```
Dim bgDiv As HtmlElement = bingCheck.Document.GetElementById("bgDiv")
Dim bgimage As String = DirectCast(bgDiv.DomElement, mshtml.IHTMLElement2) _
                        .currentStyle _
                        .backgroundImage
```

In the bgimage variable, you'll find the same output as with the previous method:

> url("http://be.bing.com/az/hprichbg?p=rb%2fPenzanceHarbor_ROW9689010992_1366x768.jpg")

What is the problem what I was talking about before? Well, you cannot use the [`WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) as the CSS is not yet (not always) applied, and thus the `getComputedStyle` function (or the `Style` property) will give you `Nothing` in return for the background image. You can either use a timer to look for the property, or else you can use a button which you manually click after the page is loaded (and in the click event you retrieve the background image).

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, the style property of HtmlElement is a string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.style.aspx

It is name value pairs separated by semi-colons.

`style-name1:value1;...;[style-nameN:valueN;]`

So you will need to parse out the value you need.

```
Dim styles as String() = bgDiv.Style.Split(";")
```